# Casting a custom type from VB6 to a List<> in C#?

Tags: c#, vb6, casting

Ok.

I have a VB6 compiled DLL that i have imported to a webservice(C# ASMX).

In VB6 i have this following types:

```
Public Type typeAccountInfo
    singular        As String
    code             As String
    description     As String
End Type

Public Type timeSheetRowPost
    lock            As Boolean
    code            As String
    from            As Long
    to              As Long
    fakt            As Boolean
    ik              As String
    ek              As String
    ak              As String
    accounts()      As typeAccountInfo
End Type

Public Type timeSheetDayPosts
    date            As String
    scheduleFrom    As Long
    scheduleTo      As Long
    break           As Long
    dagPost()       As timeSheetRowPost
End Type

Public Type timeSheet
    period            As String
    dayCount          As Long
    days()       As timeSheetDayPosts
End Type
```

TimeSheet > timeSheetDayPosts > timeSheetRowPosts > typeAccountInfo

I have a VB6 function that gets all the data i need.

When i implement this in my webservice asmx, i do it in the following way:

```
 public List<returnType> myFunction(input parameters){

  List<timeSheet> VB6Array = new List<timeSheet>();
  VB6Array = new List<timeSheet>((timeSheet[])VBWrapper.myVB6Func(input params));


  // at this point VB6Array holds all the data i need. And all i need (want) at this point is to be able to cast this VB6(system.array) to a List<> object that i can return as my returntype. 

 // Pseudo : List<ReturnType> myNewReturnType = new List<ReturnType>((ReturnType[])VB6Array); 

 // However all my tries has been without success....and what i get is You must implement a default accessor on System.Array because it inherits from ICollection.

 return myNewReturnType;
 }
```

Any tips and/or pointers on how to cast or convert a VB6 type (system.array) to a List<> will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to manually loop through the list and copy the data to a new

```
List<your_new_similar_class>
```

at least if you want a quick fix.

Comment: i had my hopes up, but it gave me: 
    cannot convert type 'system.collections.generic.list<API.timeSheet>' to 'List<timeSheet>' via a built in conversion

Comment: Sorry close but no cigar Da_smokes.  btw its bad for your health.

Comment: Manually looping through the list and adding them my my own types worked fine, it was just a matter of howto.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
VB6Array = ((List<API.timeSheet>)VBWrapper.myVB6Func(input params))
.Select(x => new timeSheet { period = x.period, ... }).ToList();
```

Comment: It didn't solve the problem per sé, but it opened up some thoughts. The problem is solved though.